# OpenJPA: Multiple columns to List or Array

Tags: jpa, openjpa

I've got an legacy database with colums like that: value_1, value_2, value_3...

For a new project I want these columns to one list or an array

```java
@Entity
public class Example {

   @????
   private List<String> values;
   or
   private String[];
}
```

How should i write the annotations make it work?

I tried it with an custom ValueHandler, but no success. I also can't find any example how to solve the problem or an good example for an custom ValueHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Column(name = "value_1")
private String value1;

@Column(name = "value_2")
private String value2;

public List<String> getValues() {
    return Arrays.asList(value1, value2);
}
```

Comment: Ok, so can I read the data as List. But if I change something in the List, the data will not send back to the database. Or I'm wrong?

Comment: No, it won't. But you can add a setter to your entity and do the symmetric operation: `value1 = list.get(0); value2 = list.get(1);`.